# Azure Notification Hub Billing

Tags: azure, push-notification, billing

I have a question about Azure Notification Hub Billing ([Prices here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/)) 
If I send a 1 message that fans out to (say) 10 client devices is that billed as 1 message or 10?

This kind of implies that that it would be 10 but it's a little unclear

> Pushes include all notifications delivered to the platform
>   notification services (e.g. Windows Notification Service, Apple Push
>   Notification Service, Google Cloud Messaging, Microsoft Push
>   Notification Service). Push allowance is prorated and capped on a
>   daily basis.

(Hope this is an ok place to ask this, there are a few Azure billing questions and none seem to have been closed so I'm assuming this is accepted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would pay a flat fee of $22 (USD) per Unit for that example.

You are charged per "unit" where a unit on "Basic" (for example) includes:

- unlimited device registrations
- up to 500,000 pushes per month (or 16,667 per day)

If you publish 1 message that fans out to 10 devices you have generated 10 pushes.  If you did not exceed the 16,667 messages in a day you'd pay $22 for a single unit.

If you need more than that you would need to scale the number of units (maximum of 9 for Basic / unlimited for Standard) to allow you to meet your demand.

Comment: I've looked into this a bit more and I think you're on the right track but it's not $22/day it's $22/unit (500k messages per month which works out to ~16k/day), I've edited your answer to reflect that

Comment: Great. Thanks for improving my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to perceive this is by considering total devices that have been reached out to using Notifications Hub; irrespective of the platforms being pushed on.

Example: 5-Android, 2-Windows, 1-iOS = 8 pushes!